# Text in p tag not left aligned properly

Tags: html, css, fonts, text-alignment, text-align

I have two lines of text in a p tag that I break with a br tag.
But they don't seem to align properly, this is not for every letter, but in my case the L has a little whitespace left to it.

[Check image for whitespace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ep2j.png)

This is my html code:

```
<p class="footer-title">LET'S WORK <br> TOGETHER</p>
```

And this is my css code for the class:

```
.footer-title {
    font-size: 45px;
    color: #FF4545;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

Why are those particular letters not aligned? And how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These extra whitespaces are called [**"sidebearings"**](https://ilovetypography.com/typography-terms/typography-terms-s/) and are defined in the font's metrics – so the alignment is an expected result.

Depending on the used `font-family`, its width and also the current font-size, the whitespace/offsets will be more or less perceivable.

You could mitigate this by applying a negative margin as suggested by [@od-c0d3r.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73742792/text-in-p-tag-not-left-aligned-properly/73744370#73743230)
Just use relative units like `em` for a more responsive adjustment.

```js
range.addEventListener('change', (e)=>{
  document.body.style.fontSize = e.currentTarget.value+'px';
});
```

```css
.wrap {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}

.footer-title {
  margin: 0px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: Arial;
  margin-left: -0.07em;
}
```

```html
<p style="font-size:16px;">font-size: 
<input id="range" type="range" min="24" max="200" step="2" value="72" >
</p>
<div class="wrap">
<p class="footer-title">LET'S WORK <br> TOGETHER</p>
</div>
```

If you need a perfectly cropped text element, you could create a `<svg>` element via [opentype.js](https://github.com/opentypejs/opentype.js).
See this [codepen example](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/XWZGVbZ).

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, I inspected the attached image.

I think the issue is related to the font type being used because I also see a whitespace after the `L` letter.

- Please try to use another font and see if the issue remains.

UPDATE:

So as we expected it, it is something related to font design.
you can work around it with that.

```css
.footer-title {
    font-size: 42px;
    color: #FF4545;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
}

.adjust-left {
    margin-left: -4px;
}
```

```html
<p class="footer-title">
    <span class="adjust-left">LET'S WORK</span><br>TOGETHER
</p>
```

I added the left border, so you can see they are aligned. you can remove it.

Comment: I tried Helvetica, Inter and Arial, they all produce the same result. When I used the default "serif" font-family, the problem went away.

Comment: Yep, as I expected. it's something related to font designing.
I will update my answer on how to fix it,

Comment: I already thought of that, but this margin-left value will be dependant on the font-size of the text

Comment: That's true @EthanVandenBleeken , Imo unless we pay for a premium font, only then all the font letters would have the same spaces and will be easy aligned.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be a break between this 2 sentences, use 2 different

tags.

```
<p class="footer-title"> LET'S WORK </p>
<p class="footer-title">TOGETHER</p>
```

Comment: I already tried this, this doesn't help with the alignment.